# Pandas .loc KeyError

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Estoy realizando un ejercicio para usar el unitest, pero me genera error el código, quisiera que alguien me pueda explicar por qué esta saliendo mal. Quiero indicar que este es el código del curso, yo simplemente lo copie y lo ejecute pero me da error.

```
> import pandas as pd
>df =d.read_csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kshedden/statswpy/master/NHANES/merged/nhanes_2015_2016.csv")
> df.index = range(1, df.shape[0]+1) 
> pd.Series.mean(df[df.RIDAGEYR > 60].loc[range(0,100), 'BPXSY1']) 


> --------------------------------------------------------------------------
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
/tmp/ipykernel_9999/2822762063.py in <module>
----> 1 pd.Series.mean(df[df.RIDAGEYR > 60].loc[range(0,100), 'BPXSY1'])

KeyError: '[0, 2, 4, 5, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 33, 35, 37, 38, 39, 41, 42, 43, 47, 48, 49, 51, 52, 53, 55, 56, 58, 59, 60, 62, 63, 64, 65, 66, 67, 68, 69, 70, 71, 73, 74, 76, 77, 80, 83, 85, 86, 87, 88, 89, 91, 92, 93, 94, 95, 96, 97, 98, 99] not in index'
```

Si alguien puede ayudarme sería de mucha ayuda. Gracias.

Comment: Un primer fallo está en el método 'pd.read_csv'. Te palta la p

Answer (score 1):

Buen día,

Cuando se aplica el filtro `df.RIDAGEYR > 60` al `dataframe` si únicamente haces esa parte vas a poder ver que el resultado no incluye los índices que te dice en el error. Es decir, el filtro:

```
df[df.RIDAGEYR > 60]
```

Devuelve un `dataframe` en el que únicamente las filas donde `RIDAGEYR` sea mayor a 60

Entonces al querer seleccionar las filas en el rango `range(0,100)` devuelve el error diciendo "No puedo encontrar todos los índices que enlisto a continuación"

```
KeyError: '[0, 2, 4, 5, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 33, 35, 37, 38, 39, 41, 42, 43, 47, 48, 49, 51, 52, 53, 55, 56, 58, 59, 60, 62, 63, 64, 65, 66, 67, 68, 69, 70, 71, 73, 74, 76, 77, 80, 83, 85, 86, 87, 88, 89, 91, 92, 93, 94, 95, 96, 97, 98, 99] not in index'
```

Para solucionarlo puedes cambiar la selección de filas de un rango a un filtro. Es decir, cambiar `.loc[range(0,100), 'BPXSY1']` (Rango de 0-100) por el filtro `.loc[:100, 'BPXSY1']` (Que en otras palabras dice, dame lo que tengas desde el inicio hasta la fila 100)

Si lo agregamos al filtro anterior vamos a tener esto

```
df[df.RIDAGEYR > 60].loc[:100, 'BPXSY1']
```

Que devuelve esto

```
1     128.0
3     138.0
6     116.0
14    124.0
15    132.0
22    148.0
23    140.0
30    122.0
31    146.0
32    160.0
34    120.0
36    150.0
40    124.0
44    158.0
45    144.0
46    168.0
50    134.0
54    146.0
57    196.0
61    132.0
72    138.0
75    134.0
78    164.0
79    106.0
81    150.0
82    114.0
84    142.0
90    134.0
Name: BPXSY1, dtype: float64
```

Como puedes ver, no todas las filas de los primeros 100 índices cumplen con el filtro `df.RIDAGEYR > 60` y por eso se muestran únicamente las filas que sí lo cumplan

Por último obtenemos el promedio

```
pd.Series.mean(df[df.RIDAGEYR > 60].loc[:100, 'BPXSY1'])
```

Y el resultado

```
139.57142857142858
```

**Edición:** si lo que te interesa son las primeras `n` filas puedes utilizar `iloc` como lo pusiste en tus comentarios

```
pd.Series.mean(df[df.RIDAGEYR > 60].iloc[:100]['BPXSY1'])
```

Esto devuelve el promedio de las primeras 100 filas del filtro deseado

```
136.29166666666666
```

Comment: Gracias, muchas gracias por su ayuda, no habia entendido porque pasaba eso, quisiera saber si eso ya no se puede hacer por rangos, es que ese código es de un curso, y mi pregunta es si esa forma de hacerlo cambio y ya no debe hacerse así. Gracias.

Comment: La cosa es que según el ejercicio el range(0,100) lo que va a hacer es que me va a mostrar en ese caso las 100 columnas que cumplan la indicación de que la media sea mayor que 60, entonces, no necesariamente debe ser de la fila 0, a 100, sino puede ser  diferentes filas, por ejemplo, si aplicaramos el metodo .iloc sería asi: df[df.RIDAGEYR > 60].iloc[range(0,5), :]  y me da 5 filas, pero no necesariamente las primeras 5, como hago entonces para hacer lo mismo con loc.

Comment: Buen día, `loc` devuelve elementos en base al nombre de la fila (Serían los índices) o columna, no sería posible hacerlo directamente con `range()`. ¿Sería posible que en el documento que tienes en realidad sea `iloc` pero tal vez la `i` no se vea claramente?

Comment: @OscarNavarrete, agregué en la respuesta el ejemplo con `iloc` para que esté completa y otros usuarios también puedan ver la diferencia

Comment: Esta es la respuesta del ejercicio utilizando .loc   ->                                                                pd.Series.mean(df[df.RIDAGEYR > 60].loc[range(0,100), 'BPXSY1']) 
                                                                                                                                        Esta es la respuesta utilizando .iloc ->                                                                   print(pd.Series.mean(df[df.RIDAGEYR > 60].iloc[range(0,100), 16]))

Comment: Si, es probable. `iloc` necesita el número de filas y columnas, otra forma de hacerlo es cómo puse en el ejemplo, pasando el filtro de columna aparte.